# Why the result always None with Scrapy Selector Xpath in this code?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Pro data hunters,
Am trying to scrape a web page that lists initially only 5 items, then by clicking the "see more" button it lists all other items.
am trying to pass the link within the button to the main response :
the locator is the button XPath.
[image: this is the complete root path of the button.]

```
    locator = "//div[@class='sc-AxjAm sc-pscky dyWQkt']/div[@class='ais-InstantSearch__root']/div[@class='sc-AxjAm sc-pscky btewui']/div[@class='sc-AxjAm sc-pscky cZkcda']/a[@class='sc-pQEbo dpfZiE xz9rvh-0 iJZnxt']/@href"
    see_more = response.xpath(locator).extract_first()
    if see_more is not None:
        link = response.urljoin(see_more)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse)
```

I get always the result as "None" even before clicking the button:
I tried this function to test the result:

```
    def parse(self, response): 
        yield {
          'see_more_link' : response.xpath("//div[@class='sc-AxjAm sc-pscky dyWQkt']/div[@class='ais-InstantSearch__root']/div[@class='sc-AxjAm sc-pscky btewui']/div[@class='sc-AxjAm sc-pscky cZkcda']/a[@class='sc-pQEbo dpfZiE xz9rvh-0 iJZnxt']/@href").extract_first()
    }
```

[image: this is the result is get using this xpath]

Comment: Can you please share the link of the website that you are crawling? Website behavior is just as important as code when crawling.

Comment: https://www.welcometothejungle.com/en

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html